# Bring up textfield when button is tapped

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift3, uitextfield, tvos

I'm trying to implement a feature where if a user taps on a button, it brings up the textfield for the user to type something in. Once the user is done, I want to navigate the user to another screen with text that he just typed.

How do I implement bringing up the textfield for the user to type in when the button is tapped?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present

Answer (score -1, accepted):

on the button action just add self.yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder
...
then controller.text = yourTextField.text
...